# how to give custom spacing inside a row element in qml

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I am trying to create an UI in QML which should look like this

[image]

That is, there is some extra pixel space between the textField element and the Button.

I am trying to recreate this image using QML Row Element as shown below

```
    Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Row{
        id:row_element
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        spacing:20
        width: implicitWidth
        height: implicitHeight
        RadioButton{
            id:min_timer_id
            text: "100"
            spacing: 5
        }
        RadioButton{
            id:max_timer_id
            text: "500"
            spacing: 5
        }
        RadioButton{
            id:custom_entry_rb
            text: "custom"
            spacing: 5
            width: 100
        }

        TextField{
            id:custom_entry
            placeholderText: "enter custom time"
            width: 200
        }
        Button{
            id:buttonId
            text: "start Timer"
            width: 200
            spacing: 100
        }

    }
}
```

i am not able to set the custom spacing between the text field and the button, is there a way to do it using the row Element?

My current UI looks like this:-

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to keep it within a `Row`, I would just add an invisible `Item` as a spacer.

```
Row {
    spacing: 20
    RadioButton {}
    RadioButton {}
    TextField {}

    // Size this to whatever you need.
    Item { height: 1; width: 50 }

    Button {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RowLayout` with an `Item` that has `Layout.fillWidth: true`.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    RowLayout {
        id: row_element
        spacing: 20
        anchors.top: parent.top
        width: parent.width

        RadioButton {
            id: min_timer_id

            text: "100"
            spacing: 5
        }

        RadioButton {
            id: max_timer_id

            text: "500"
            spacing: 5
        }

        RadioButton {
            id: custom_entry_rb

            text: "custom"
            spacing: 5
            width: 100
        }

        TextField {
            id: custom_entry

            placeholderText: "enter custom time"
            width: 200
        }
        Item{
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }

        Button {
            id: buttonId

            text: "start Timer"
            width: 200
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i wanted to do it specifically inside a row component.